# How to correctly setup signed url uploads for AWS S3 on Heroku?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

**The Problem**

I have a simple application running on Heroku where users can upload and view images/videos. I'm trying to use signed url. I tried [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) tutorial and [this one](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node). In fact I cloned the Github repo. The problem is when ever I try to upload an image I get these errors:

[Error] Preflight response is not successful

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load (long link) due to access control checks.

[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (img.jp2, line 0)

**Specific Question**

I think the problem might be with the S3 bucket set up since I do not have much experience with AWS. So my question is what is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Here is my CORs config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

here is the code that generates the Presigned url

```js
aws.config.region = 'us-west-1';
BUCKET = process.env.S3_BUCKET;

app.get('/account', (req, res) => res.render('account.html'));

app.get('/sign-s3', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const fileName = req.query['file-name'];
  const fileType = req.query['file-type'];
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: fileType,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };

  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.end();
    }
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: data,
      url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    };
    res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
    res.end();
  });
});
```

here is the code that tries to upload to S3

```js
function uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        alert('success')
      }
      else{
        alert('Could not upload file.');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(file);
}
```

**What has been tried**

adding

```
<AllowedMethod>OPTIONS</AllowedMethod>
```

results in

```
Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is OPTIONS
```

**Additional Notes**

I have tried chrome and safari. It turns out I had accidentally defaulted to using

```
 <AllowedHeader>authorization</AllowedHeader>
```

changing this back to

```
 <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

results in:

```
[Long link] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heroku tutorial left some details out (or needs to be updated):

The config needed to be updated:

```js
aws.config.region = 'us-west-1';
aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId:  process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the problem, you should set the `content-type` since it is used when the signature is generated as well.

`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");`

Comment: I have set the CORs in the permissions as mentioned in the tutorial. I'll edit to show what I CORs configuration I have.

Comment: Can you also allow "OPTIONS" method

Comment: `<AllowedMethod>OPTIONS</AllowedMethod>`

Comment: it says unsupported method

Comment: Are there any other settings? Does the bucket need to be public?

Comment: No. That's the whole point of presign. Are you creating a signature already

Comment: Posting now. It uses Node.js AWS SDK

Comment: i think you have posted into my answer, can you post into your question.

Comment: modified my answer for you

Comment: you basically have to set the same `content-type` that you use during signing. otherwise try removing the `content-type` from the signing process. see whether its working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out what I think the issue was. the code in the tutorial never used the secret access id/key. by adding these to the config I was able to get the upload to work for an image. I'll see if it works for videos.